# On Node .pipe(response) not working. How to return a video?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, encryption, video-streaming

I have encrypted mp4 files.

I want to decrypt and return the video data on the response without saving decrypted data on disk. That is what I am doing now:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    crypto = require('crypto'),
    encryptedFilePath = 'videos/1.mp4',
    decrypedFilePath = "tmp/1.mp4",
    algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr',
    key = "abcd1234" ;

fs.createReadStream(encryptedFilePath)
    .pipe(crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, key))
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(decrypedFilePath))
    .on("finish", function(){
        res.sendFile(decrypedFilePath);
    });
```

I would like to do something like the following, but it didn't work:

```
fs.createReadStream(encryptedFilePath)
   .pipe(crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, key))
   .pipe(response);
```

**Update 1**

I have seen the headers of both options and they are difference.

With `.pipe(response)`:

[image: With .pipe(response)]

With `res.sendFile(decrypedFilePath)`:

[image: With res.sendFile(decrypedFilePath);]

PS: I am using [Keystonejs](http://keystonejs.com/) CMS which use Nodejs/express. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any output you can share? Also - is your response object named res or response? Your code snippets disagree on what it is called.

Comment: I don't have any output. The weird thing is that I have a response, video player is shown with the time of the video (23s) but it is not played.

Comment: Regarding to response/res it was an error here on SO.

Comment: What's the behavior/result when you try to pipe to the response?